# sqlalchemy [ORM] - add/inset to multiple tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I've created the schema and 2 tables models with the relation between them.

```
class SubscriberBase(BaseModel):
    subscriber_no: int
    is_active: bool = False

class SubscriberCreate(BaseModel):
    pass


class Subscriber(SubscriberBase):
    owner: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class CustomerCreate(BaseModel):
    customer_no: int
    subscriber: Optional[List[SubscriberBase]] = None

class Customer(CustomerCreate):
    id: int
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Models:

```
class CustomerModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    customer_no= Column(Integer,index=True)
    subscriber= relationship("SubscriberModel", back_populates="owner")


class SubscriberModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subscriber'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("customer.id"))
    subscriber_no= Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    owner = relationship("CustomerModel", back_populates="subscriber")
```

for the following dictionary input:

```
test = {'customer_no': 2, 'subscriber': [{'subscriber_no': 2, 'is_active': False}, {'subscriber_no': 1, 'is_active': False}]}
```

I expect , it will insert one row to customer table ,
and 2 rows in subscriber table.

tried:

```
    db_customer = models.CustomerModel(**test)
    db.add(db_customer)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_customer)
```

Getting error :

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1675, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
    child_state, child_dict = instance_state(child), instance_dict(child)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

How does sqlalchemy orm insert to multiple tables?
Is it possible to insert both customer and subscriber tables in one insert ?

---

@van

Updating the post with more Info:
Im Working with fastapi where the "customer" (the "test" dict i mention above)
is is actually the pydantic , and i did tried the following:

```
@customer_router.post("/customer/")
def overloaded_create_customer(customer: CustomerCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    
    db_customer = CustomerModel(**dict(customer))
    db.add(db_customer)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_customer)
```

It return similar error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1675, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
    child_state, child_dict = instance_state(child), instance_dict(child)
AttributeError: 'SubscriberBase' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a ORM model instance (like you try with the `CustomerModel`) is not the way to do it. Instead, with the assumption that those are pydantic schemas, you should try something along these lines:

```
# create pydantic model from the dictionary
cust_schema = schemas.Customer.parse_obj(test)

# convert to ORM model
db_customer = models.CustomerModel(**dict(cust_schema))

# ... (rest of your code)
```

Comment: thanks , I think that what i did , Im working with fastapi ,
I have the customer pydantic model ready -i update the post with more infor .

Comment: Still struggling finding solution .